# Using USB ports on my monitor?

Tags: usb, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, usb-c

I have an LG Ultra HD display (27 in, 4K) with a few USB ports on the back. As outputs it has USB-C, DisplayPort, and HDMI. On my MacBook, if I plug in the USB-C, I can also use the USB ports on the back of the monitor. On my PC, if I use HDMI or DP, I don't have access to the USB ports.

Do I absolutely need to have USB-C support on my graphics card on my PC to access those ports then? I'd like to swap between my PC and my MacBook easily, using the same keyboard and mouse, and these ports would make that trivial.

This is what my I/O looks like. My PC graphics card is an RX 580 8GB and the PC runs Windows 10.

[image: i/o]

Comment: The way the USB (Hub) functionality is provided to a device is through the USB Type-C port.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I absolutely need to have USB-C support on my graphics card on my
> PC to access those ports then?

No, I am quite sure not. I have a monitor like that on my Windows 10 Desktop.  I plug the monitor input USB into a USB port on the computer.

This is not connected to the graphics card in any way.

Once connected, the monitor out USB ports are good to go.

Another approach is to attach a Hub (may need a short USB cord) to the back of the computer.

Comment: The trouble is that there is no USB output - the USB ports you see on the back in the image are inputs (a hub). I was wondering if I had to use the USB-C output to gain access to those ports. If so, it seems like this monitor is really meant for laptops/desktops with USB-C.

Comment: If all the USB ports are inputs (seems to me there should only be one input) then connect a hub to the back of the computer as that will work as weill

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you are also carrying 'picture' to that USB-C port, you must be carrying USB3 (late 3.1 or 3.2) to correctly allow the display to act as a full hub.

Your GPU strictly has nothing to do with that, but several of the services provided by the hub will require full USB-C connectivity. Onwards DP & HDMI will be most affected if your computer's USB ports cannot carry full Thunderbolt spec USB 3.2 (or late 3.1, there were several changes during the lifetime of 3.1) If your USB-C port on the computer states 3.2 or 3.1 with DP, then you should be OK.

Neither HDMI nor DP alone can carry the other protocols.